# How To Show Tooltip In Sparkline Chart From Code

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a dashboard page where if a user clicks on a point in a graph then all graphs with that unique identifier in a point should enable the tooltip to show. This works for all charts except for sparklines. The live demo below shows the default highcharts sparkline demo but mine just has one point (a bar graph with one point). The error is still the same:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltipOptions' of undefined
>       at a.Tooltip.refresh (highcharts.src.js:22676)

The code I am using to show/hide tooltips is:

```
function chartPointClick(pointidx) {
    var chartArray = Highcharts.charts;
    for (var i = 0; i < chartArray.length; i++) {
        var thechart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        var theData = thechart.series[0].data;

        if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'TD') {
            var theSeries = thechart.series[0]
                console.log(theSeries);
                thechart.tooltip.refresh(theSeries.options.data[0]);
        }
        thechart.redraw();
    }
}
```

This is called via the plotOptions.series.events method:

```
events: {
        click: function (event) {
            chartPointClick(event.point.idx);
        }
}
```

How can I activate the sparkline tooltips?

Live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2j4ncd1g/2/).

EDIT -
Live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/1m0wLfqv/4/) using single bar chart which is not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip `refresh` method accepts the first argument only as an array of points:

```
    if (thechart.renderTo.tagName == 'TD') {
        var theSeries = thechart.series[0]
        thechart.tooltip.refresh([theSeries.points[0]]);
    }
```

Next problem here is `outside` option for the tooltip, which causes another error. I recommend you to use:

```
td,
th {
    ...
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qx31oa7m/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside

Comment: This works for the jsFiddle but not for my use case. There is no `theSeries.points[0]`. Let me update question with my exact case.

Comment: Hi wergeld, There is no `points` in series, because you used `update` method without `redraw`. For the `refresh` method, the point is required, so you can redraw the chart each time or change the color in a different way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tdasfw4r/

Comment: That did it! Thank you!